# Is this a "good DBA.se" question to you?

Tags: discussion

[Why should I use Visual Studio 2010 over SSMS for my database development?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7599/why-should-i-use-visual-studio-2010-over-ssms-for-my-database-development)

Nick and I got into a discussion via various places on the Stacks and he felt encouraged to ask it as a question on dba (and then he asked on chat.dba.se if this was appropriate). Since I'm too close to the question, I can't really make a good judgement call.

So what do you, the community, think? This is, after all, a community run site.

Answer (score 6):

At first, I was going to say 'no', since the question title seems argumentative and too subjective.

Then I opened the question and found that what it really was asking was what does VS2010 offer that SSMS doesn't. Seems like a great question for DBA, since these are tools DBAs<sup>1</sup> use.

<sub><sup>1</sup>DBAs in this case = microsoft toadies!<sup>2</sup></sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>These are my opinions only</sub>

Comment: Some of us are, unfortunately, forced to use SQL Server databases, and in that case, Microsoft simply does have the superior software.

Answer (score 4):

From the responses to @Nick's question so far, it would appear the capabilities of VS2010 for database development are not well understood. As such, this has the potential to be a useful signpost for the community.

As @DTest mentions, it could be interpreted as a subjective question but hopefully the answers will make it less so.